# Custom callout for current location

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotation

I want to display a 2 line label in the callout for current location.
**MKUserLocation and not MKAnnotation**
Can anybody help with how is it possible?

Am sure It would be possible with custom Callout.. But not sure how to create it for MKUserLocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you can create custom annotation callout and want to use instead of default callout for userlocation. To get this done one need to get reference of current location MKAnnotationView. One can get this reference anywhere but it is better to get it as soon as user location is determined.

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation 
    {
     MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [mapView viewForAnnotation:userLocation];
    annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;

//your customization here

    }
```

Or use following method

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
    MKAnnotationView *aV; 
         for (aV in views) {
                if ([aV.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
                    MKAnnotationView* annotationView = aV;
                     annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
    //your customization here

                }
        }
}
```

and if want to change in `canShowCallout` property in runtime then one can use following

```
    for (AnnotationClass* annotation in mapView.annotations) 
        {
            if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]] )
            {
                 MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];
                 annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
//your customization here

            }
        }
```

Comment: +1 -- very helpful but the duplication of code is distracting so I'm editing it for you!

Comment: didUpdateUserLocation is not guaranteed to be called (i.e if location tracking failed for some reason, in that case user location pin turns gray) therefore `didAddAnnotationViews` is the only way to reliably disable callout on user location pin.

Answer (score 5):

In the `viewForAnnotation` method you could try this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)map:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{
    if(self._mapView.userLocation==annotation){
       self._mapView.userLocation.title=@"some text";
       self._mapView.userLocation.subtitle=@"some text";
       return nil;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought you wanted to display just 2 lines. Then, you should subclass MKAnnotationView.

Comment: when the `if` is `true` the annotation is the MKUserLocation.

Comment: can we prevent the default callout of default current location?